# Spoiled protein shake?

Tags: milk

On my way to work which is about an hour drive I had brought along my protein shake which contains 16oz of milk. The whole car ride was nice and cool due to the ac. Once I got to work I accidentally left it out for another hour in the car. I just grabbed it and put it in the freezer so it will cool. It did not smell bad. Is this still okay to drink? Or has it been too long?

Comment: How warm was it when you pick it up from the car ? IMO it should be OK.

Comment: @Max - needing the a/c on in May would probably hint they live somewhere 'warm'.

Comment: @Max FL, its already toasty here